Camel Filter shows problem during deployment in Tomcat 9 On Windows 10
We are using camel filter in the camel route definition in XML file. But it is not deployed in Tomcat9 (Tomcat 9.0.85).
But when we are are running our application from development IDE (ECLIPSE or STS) the application is deployed.
Can anyone tell me what is actual reason of such problem and how to resolve this problem ?
(Java version is used Java SE 8.0 [ java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242] )
Operating system is Windows 10.
We tried to run the application in WINDOWS and in LINUX both. Only in Windows we are facing problem.
Route definition in XML DSL -
<route id="routeNach4">
    <from uri="file:D:\\deployments\\DSP\\ChannelPath\\NPCIPMT\\achdebit?delete=true&filter=#checkBankActivityStatus" />
    <log message="NACH DEBIT PROCESS : [${body}]" />
    <to uri="file:D:\\deployments\\DSP\\ChannelPath\\NPCIPMT\\achdebitbackup?noop=true" />
<doTry>
    <process ref="achDebitProcessor" />
    <doCatch>      
       <exception>java.io.IOException</exception>
       <exception>java.lang.IllegalStateException</exception>
       <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
    </doCatch>
</doTry>
</route>

Error during deployment :
2024-05-09 14:01:26,945 ERROR - Context initialization failed
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route routeNach4: Route(routeNach4)[[From[file:D:\\deployments\\DSP\\ChannelPa... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: file://D:%5C%5Cdeployments%5C%5CDSP%5C%5CChannelPath%5C%5CNPCIPMT%5C%5Cachdebit?delete=true&filter=%23checkBankActivityStatus due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: filter as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value #checkBankActivityStatus
at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1826)
at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:136)
at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.start(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:370)
at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:425)
at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:95)

Thanks in advance,
